# use of getsession() in http sessions

Tags: http, servlets

How come the following code snippet always enters the else block?

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

        request.getRequestDispatcher("link.html").include(request, response);

        HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        if(session!=null){
        String name=(String)session.getAttribute("name");
        out.print("Hello, "+name+" Welcome to Profile");
        }
        else{
            out.print("Please login first");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html").include(request, response);
        }
        out.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> from java doc getSession() Returns the current session associated with this request,
>   or if the request does not have a session, creates one.

In your code

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession();
```

It will check for current session associated with request and if there is not any,then it is going to create one.
So the check `if(session!=null){` will always be true.

If you want to check that if session is present then only return HttpSession object else return null,then you can use one overloaded version of this method

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
```

### See Also

- [JavaDoc getSession()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession())
- [JavaDoc getSession(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession(boolean))

Comment: I cite from the question: *"always enters the else block"*

Comment: getSession() should ALWAYS return a non-null entity. So how come it enters the else block? Any ideas as to what might be the reason?